# what is the difference between homozygous and heterozygous duplication?

Tags: genetics, molecular-genetics, human-genetics, population-genetics

In a genetic test result it's written

```
homozygous duplication
```

or

```
heterozygous duplication
```

Does it mean four copies of the same gene for homozygous duplication and three copies for heterozygous duplication?